# Kubernetes keeps crashing (Vagrant master+3-node set)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes, vagrant, containerd

To demonstrate what I've done, I put together a repo with a Vagrant + Cloud-init config.

https://github.com/johnmanko/vagrant-k8s-cluster

Basically, Kubernetes keeps crashing, and I don't know why.  Half the time I can't connect to inspect things.  `top` doesn't show any excessive cpu/mem usage.

```
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl get pods -A
The connection to the server 192.168.56.21:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
kube-system   coredns-5dd5756b68-lfktv             0/1     Completed          7                28m
kube-system   coredns-5dd5756b68-vxzcn             1/1     Running            5 (5m6s ago)     28m
kube-system   etcd-kubemaster                      1/1     Running            8 (4m2s ago)     28m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubemaster            1/1     Running            9 (88s ago)      29m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubemaster   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   11 (4m32s ago)   29m
kube-system   kube-proxy-s2vkv                     1/1     Running            13 (5m56s ago)   28m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubemaster            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   12 (3m8s ago)    28m
kube-system   weave-net-rsd7x                      0/2     CrashLoopBackOff   11 (46s ago)     17m
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl logs kube-scheduler-kubemaster -p
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kube-scheduler-kubemaster" not found
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl logs kube-scheduler-kubemaster -p -n kube-system
The connection to the server 192.168.56.21:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl get pods -A
The connection to the server 192.168.56.21:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

When I can type fast enough to grab a log:

```
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl logs kube-scheduler-kubemaster -p -n kube-system
I1211 16:56:51.716017       1 serving.go:348] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
W1211 16:56:51.969869       1 authentication.go:368] Error looking up in-cluster authentication configuration: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/extension-apiserver-authentication": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.969893       1 authentication.go:369] Continuing without authentication configuration. This may treat all requests as anonymous.
W1211 16:56:51.969901       1 authentication.go:370] To require authentication configuration lookup to succeed, set --authentication-tolerate-lookup-failure=false
I1211 16:56:51.971903       1 server.go:154] "Starting Kubernetes Scheduler" version="v1.28.4"
I1211 16:56:51.971922       1 server.go:156] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
I1211 16:56:51.972965       1 secure_serving.go:213] Serving securely on 127.0.0.1:10259
I1211 16:56:51.973076       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:202] "Starting controller" name="client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file"
I1211 16:56:51.973135       1 shared_informer.go:311] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I1211 16:56:51.973153       1 tlsconfig.go:240] "Starting DynamicServingCertificateController"
W1211 16:56:51.974053       1 reflector.go:535] pkg/server/dynamiccertificates/configmap_cafile_content.go:206: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dextension-apiserver-authentication&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:51.974113       1 reflector.go:147] pkg/server/dynamiccertificates/configmap_cafile_content.go:206: Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dextension-apiserver-authentication&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.974190       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:51.974218       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.974283       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.CSINode: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csinodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:51.974306       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.CSINode: failed to list *v1.CSINode: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csinodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.974366       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.CSIStorageCapacity: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csistoragecapacities?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:51.974395       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.CSIStorageCapacity: failed to list *v1.CSIStorageCapacity: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csistoragecapacities?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.974450       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:51.974478       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.974537       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.StorageClass: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:51.974561       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.StorageClass: failed to list *v1.StorageClass: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.974617       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DSucceeded%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:51.974640       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DSucceeded%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DFailed&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:56:51.974703       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/policy/v1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:56:56.570686       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.StatefulSet: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/apps/v1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:57:02.094444       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:57:02.094639       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.ReplicationController: failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
W1211 16:57:02.326461       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/apps/v1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:57:02.326682       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.StatefulSet: failed to list *v1.StatefulSet: Get "https://192.168.56.21:6443/apis/apps/v1/statefulsets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 192.168.56.21:6443: connect: connection refused
E1211 16:57:05.294891       1 server.go:214] "waiting for handlers to sync" err="context canceled"
I1211 16:57:05.295817       1 leaderelection.go:250] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/kube-scheduler...
I1211 16:57:05.295861       1 server.go:238] "Requested to terminate, exiting"
```

From `/var/log/container/kube-apiserver-xxx.log`:

```
2023-12-12T05:28:46.455303494Z stderr F W1212 05:28:46.455224       1 logging.go:59] [core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #4] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "1
27.0.0.1:2379", ServerName: "127.0.0.1", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused"
2023-12-12T05:28:46.455514253Z stderr F W1212 05:28:46.455457       1 logging.go:59] [core] [Channel #94 SubChannel #95] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr:
"127.0.0.1:2379", ServerName: "127.0.0.1", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused"
2023-12-12T05:28:46.455632271Z stderr F W1212 05:28:46.455576       1 logging.go:59] [core] [Channel #31 SubChannel #32] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr:
"127.0.0.1:2379", ServerName: "127.0.0.1", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused"
2023-12-12T05:28:46.455798916Z stderr F W1212 05:28:46.455744       1 logging.go:59] [core] [Channel #67 SubChannel #68] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr:
"127.0.0.1:2379", ServerName: "127.0.0.1", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused"
```

I've destroyed the cluster and recreated it several times, going through the steps trying to find something that's causing it, but almost immediately as `kubeadm init` is starts to fail.

The repo is the exact process I'm using to create the cluster.  Any insight on to how I can determine the constant crashing?

Comment: The following answer fixed my problem.  Namely, containerd didn't like the config file, and I generated the default and modified it afterwards: (`SystemdCgroup = true`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/73141339/1686575